# Perl .pl file downloads instead of being executed

Tags: apache2, perl, cgi, otrs

I'm trying to get OTRS 4.0 working on Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed all instructions to [install from source](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/manual-installation-of-otrs.html).

When I open the site (localhost/otrs/index.pl), an empty .pl-file is served for download. Apparently Apache finds the index.pl, but does not know what to do with it.

- OTRS is installed with all relevant perl modules (checked by install script)
- Vhost is copied from scripts folder in OTRS
- hosts is updated for the local test domain
- Apache is restarted

**Modules**

```
cgi.load -> ../mods-available/cgi.load
perl.load -> ../mods-available/perl.load
```

**Question**

How can I get Perl working with Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have set the following path in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:
`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/path/to/cgi-bin/"` and that your scripts are in that folder.

If your scripts ends on .pl make sure to change the line
`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` to `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl`
in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and check that it is not commented out.

`Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI` needs to set in your virtual host.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There was no AddHandler in apache2.conf. I've added it. There was no ScriptAlias either. OTRS has its own ScriptAlias for cgi-bin: `ScriptAlias /otrs/ "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/"`. So this alias should point to the OTRS cgi-bin? Adding the cgi-bin ScriptAlias doesn't change anything after a restart.

Comment: If the Scripts are in `/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/` it should be: `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/"`. Also check your virtual host, as I edited in my answer.

Comment: I've updated the virtualhost, and still no change.

Comment: I just had a chance to take a more detailed look at OTRS. All necessary config is allready provided in the `/opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf`. Have you copied that file to your `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory and enabled it with `a2ensite apache2-httpd.include`?

Answer (score 4):

Waking the dead but with the answer.
Do this:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

sudo service apache2 restart
```

and it works.

Comment: Or `a2enmod cgid`